# web.config's authorization list order?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to understand the difference between :

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="*" />
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

vs  ( changed order)

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
   <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

[**I've read that**](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=2wg5LCKuChcC&pg=PA965&lpg=PA965&dq=%22When%20evaluating%20rules,%20ASP.NET%20scans%20through%20the%20list%20from%20top%20to%20bottom%22&source=bl&ots=HjB7cOweFJ&sig=7nt6RqzHQRwodw-a1fEqvcFBPFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Qo3wUtiWDe3G7AaI04DwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22When%20evaluating%20rules,%20ASP.NET%20scans%20through%20the%20list%20from%20top%20to%20bottom%22&f=false) :

> When evaluating rules, ASP.NET scans through the list from top to
>   bottom. As soon as it finds an applicable rule, it **stops** its search.

So , in the first example : it will determine that the rule `<allow users="*">` applies to the current request and will **not** evaluate the second line.

But I've also read that :

> **Reversing** the order of these two lines, however, will **deny** anonymous
>   users (by matching the first rule) and *allow all other* users (by
>   matching the second rule).

**Question :**

Why does the rule of  *"As soon as it finds an applicable rule, it stops its search"* is not apply in the second example ?

I was expecting that it will deny all anonymous users and stop ( without getting into  `<allow users="*" />`).

Comment: _not appear to be about programming_....yeah right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real contradiction here so this statement is still true

> When evaluating rules, ASP.NET scans through the list from top to bottom. As soon as it finds an applicable rule, it stops its search.

However you need to understand what are the `*` and `?` means.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719554%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
Identity    Description  
*           Refers to all identities  
?           Refers to the anonymous identity
```

So this means that `*` matches all users both: anonymous and authenticated users, however `?` only matches the anonymous users.

So lets walk trough the two configuration:

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="*" />
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

- A "regular" user comes in -> `users="*"` matches -> the access is allowed and the second rule is not checked.
- An anonymous user comes in -> `users="*"` matches because it also matches anonymous users -> the access is allowed and  the second rule is not checked.

But in the second case:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
   <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

- An "regular" user comes in -> the `users="?"` **does not match** because it only matches anonymous users -> checking the second role: `users="*"` which matches ->  the access is allowed.
- An anonymous user comes in -> `users="?"` matches -> the access is denied and  the second rule is not checked.